# compare Javascript Output results and display another result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need output result with input data.

for example, 164 and style a is S, 186 and style b is XL

- i made a 'height(number) + style(radio button)' input and output code
- compare output result(164a, 186b) make another output result
- like if outputresult==164a display S, else outputresult==180b display XL...
- last output result is 4(hood, sleeve, shirts A, shirts B)
- and need output result change immediately

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('.height,.style').on('change, input',
    function() {
      $('.total').val($('.height').val() + $('.style:checked').val());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="person_total">
      <td><input name="height" type="number" class="span1 height" maxlength="3"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="s">
        <label for="kjc-small">S</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="n" checked="">
        <label for="kjc-normal">N</label>
        <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="b">
        <label for="kjc-big">B</label>
      </td>
      <td><input name="total" type="text" id="total" class="span1 total" readonly=""></td>
      <div id="" class="">last result A(hood)</div>
      <div id="" class="">last result B(shirts A)</div>
      <div id="" class="">last result C(shirts B)</div>
      <div id="" class="">last result D(sleeve)</div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: Agree with above comment, what is the issue you are having?

Comment: sorry, i'm a newbie i don't know how i ask

Answer (score 0):

i modify code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
$('.height,.style').on('change, input', 
function(){
$('.total').val($('.height').val() * $('.style:checked').val());
});

$('.height,.style').on('change, input', 
function(){
    var total2 = $( 'input#total' ).val();
    if ( total2 == 180 ) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 's';
    } else if ( total2 == 360 ) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'm';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'xl';
    }
});
}
</script>
```